# Kubernetes internal hostname is resolved to localhost

Tags: go, kubernetes, microservices

I'm trying to use internal service DNS for service-to-service HTTP communication.

If I try to curl a pod from another deployment pod it is working but unable to use it in golang net/http service

```
2023/01/27 15:48:37 oauth2.go:90: oauth2 url  http://hydra-admin.microservices.svc.cluster.local:4445/oauth2/auth/requests/login/accept
2023/01/27 15:48:37 oauth2.go:101: Unable to make http request  Put "http://localhost:4445/admin/oauth2/auth/requests/login/accept?login_challenge=b569006c8b834a298cf1cd72e2424953": dial tcp [::1]:4445: connect: connection refused
```

hydra-admin.microservices.svc.cluster.local is resolved to localhost when the API call is made

but curl works as you see below

```
/ # curl -X PUT http://hydra-admin:4445/admin/oauth2/auth/requests/login/accept?login_challenge=6f51146e49c54b739de8a37b25a72349
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Unable to decode body because: EOF"}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Just post the text itself, formatted as a code sample. That makes it *much* easier to read.

Comment: added the texts from the image

Comment: What are the compile options you are using to build your `k8s` image? `CGO_ENABLED` setting? Build tags etc?

Comment: go build -ldflags "-s -w -X main.BuildRevision=$CI_COMMIT_SHA -X main.BuildVersion=$CI_COMMIT_TAG -X main.BuildTime=$(date --utc +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)" -o ./bin/${EXEC_NAME}
this is my compile options, I don't see the CGO_ENABLED and I'm using golang:1.18-alpine image from gitlab pipeline. Let me try adding what you've suggested

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment, depending on how you are building your `go` executable will have an effect on how it behaves within a `k8s` environment. Are you using a `scratch` image or a `CGO_ENABLED=1` image?

From the `dns` package [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/net#hdr-Name_Resolution) there's a caveat on DNS behavior

> By default the pure Go resolver is used, because a blocked DNS request
> consumes only a goroutine, while a blocked C call consumes an
> operating system thread. When cgo is available, the cgo-based resolver
> is used instead under a variety of conditions:

> ... when /etc/resolv.conf or /etc/nsswitch.conf specify the use of features
> that the Go resolver does not implement, ***and when the name being
> looked up ends in .local*** or is an mDNS name.

So I would suggest - to maximized your success rate for both external & internal DNS requests - building your `go` executable for `k8s` like so:

```
CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -tags netgo
```